# Testing React app with Jest, using Vite as a module Bundler; import.meta error

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, vite, esbuild

i am testing a React-Typescript application with Jest; my application uses Vite as a module bundler.
The issue is, everytime i run tests and jest encounters an import.meta.ENV_VAR_NAME  statement i get the following error: "SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module"

This is my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest/jest.setup.js"],
collectCoverageFrom: ["src//*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "!src//.d.ts"],
testMatch: [
    "<rootDir>/src//tests//.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "<rootDir>/src/*/.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
],
testEnvironment: "jsdom",
transform: {
    // "^.+\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "esbuild-jest",
    "^.+\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "@swc/jest",
    "^.+\.scss$": "jest-scss-transform",
    "^.+\.css$": "<rootDir>/jest/mocks/cssMock.js"
},
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
    "^.+\.module\.(css|sass|scss)$"
],
watchPlugins: [
    "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
    "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
],
resetMocks: true,
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
moduleNameMapper: {
    "\.worker": "<rootDir>/src/seo/mocks/workerMock.ts",
    "\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
};
```

In transform key of jest.config i tried using either @swc/jest and esbuild-jest, but none fixed the import.meta issue; is there a solution to this problem? Can i achieve it without using Babel?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: @Ju-riJung yes i solved it; i changed all my import.meta into process.env in order to not bother jest; as for vite, with a vite plugin called env-compatible, at compile time converts the process.env into import.meta so that vite won't be bothered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- https://codingwithmanny.medium.com/quick-jest-setup-with-vitejs-react-typescript-82f325e4323f
- refer the above link for setting up Jest in your Vite project.
- install this plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-environment)
- create `.env` file in your project root folder near package.json
- provide your env variables in `.env` files
- change all your `import.meta.env.YOUR_VAR` to `process.env.YOUR_VAR`
- open `vite.config.ts` and import `import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment';`
- add `EnvironmentPlugin('all')` in plugins. example: `plugins: [react(), EnvironmentPlugin('all')]`
- now your test will pass without `import.meta.env` error.
- the explanation behind this config is that Jest will understand `process.env.YOUR_VAR`, so if you change all your `import.meta.env.YOUR_VAR` to `process.env.YOUR_VAR` then Jest will not give error.
- But then we have to provide `vite-plugin-environment` to Vite Config so that it understands `process.env.YOUR_VAR`
- it works in production as well.

Comment: *Finally* a solution that works - thank you. Tussled with this one for entirely too long. Such an annoying constraint.

Comment: That's a lot of steps for something that just needs mocked in the jest files!

Answer (score 1):

OR! You could just mock the env vars in your Jest context. Much simpler.

(this is already answered on another SO post)
[Test suite failed to run import.meta.env.VITE_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72128718/test-suite-failed-to-run-import-meta-env-vite/74882007#74882007)