# Test suite failed to run import.meta.env.VITE_*

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vite, vue-test-utils

After adding the environment variable `import.meta.env.VITE_*` in my code, the tests with vue-test-utils started to fail, with the error:

```
Jest suite failed to run
error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node12', or 'nodenext'.
```

I have searched for some available fixes but none have worked so far.

**EDIT**

jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  globals: {},
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    "^.+\\js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["vue", "js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/tests/unit/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "tests"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

When including `module: "esnext"`, the warning below is displayed and the error remains.

> Validation Warning:
>
> Unknown option "module" with value "commonjs" was found.   This is
> probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
>
> Configuration Documentation:   https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much research, I was able to solve the case.

I had to install the `vite-plugin-environment` and `babel-plugin-transform-import-meta` libraries and make the following settings:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-import-meta"]
}
```

**tsonfig.json**

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    ...
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
...
import EnvironmentPlugin from "vite-plugin-environment"
...
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [..., EnvironmentPlugin("all")],
  ...
})
```

Also change the `import.meta.env.*` to `process.env.*`

Comment: One problem is that the ENV variable value is coming as undefined, when i run the code with jest

Comment: @manishkeer see my answer to solving this - it will ensure that the value is set when running jest.

Comment: changing the import.meta.env.* to process.env.* worked for me.

Answer (score 28):

Personally I route all my `import.meta.env` values through a single file (src/constants.ts or src/constants.js)

```
// src/constants.(js|ts)...

const {
  MODE: ENVIRONMENT,
} = import.meta.env;

export {
  ENVIRONMENT
};
```

Then in my jest tests I just mock the constants file:

```
// example.test.(js|ts)
jest.mock('src/constants', () => ({
  ENVIRONMENT: 'development',
}));
```

IMHO this is better also because you'll likely want to mock the value anyway.

Comment: This solution worked for me when 45 minutes of failed babel/jest related software dev acrobatics failed. It was simple and replaces all the difficult "modify your babel! install a plugin!" type solutions with something simple and direct. I recommend it to others.

Comment: @plutownium <3 I also spent a good hour+ trying to modify configurations before I threw my hands up in the air and used jest mocking instead. Glad I could help!

Comment: Does destructuring play nicely with vite's [static replacement](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#production-replacement)?

Comment: @jeff As far as I know - yes. I've been doing this approach for about six months without any issues. The app in all environments gets the right values set and exported from the constants file. And the jest tests work without having to do anything extra or special. :D

Comment: Well, I love you. Maybe 3 hours spent in this #$%&. Just your answer could save me. Thanks. I think this must be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Best answer, imo

Comment: Simple and to-the-point solution to this problem. I also set all my environment variables in a single file so this solution worked like a charm. One thing I'd like to add is that you don't need to mock the same file again and again in every test file, you can create a module mapping using `moduleNameMapper` in the jest.config.js file and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react + vite, I tried the following:

```
npm install --save-dev dotenv cross-env
```

to get env in standard form, then I made the following configuration in my `vite.config.js`

```js
...
import { loadEnv } from 'vite'
...
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => { 
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  return {
    plugins:[react()],
    server: {
      host:true
    },
    define: {
      'process.env.YOUR_STRING_VARIABLE': 
      JSON.stringify(env.YOUR_STRING_VARIABLE),
      'process.env.APP_USE_AVT': env.APP_USE_AVT,
    },
  };
});
```

this solved it.